# Add new points in .PLY file

Tags: python, point-cloud-library, 3d-model

i'm trying to add new line in my .ply files using PlyData:

```py
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement
import numpy

with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    plydata = PlyData.read(f)
    vertex = numpy.array([([0, 1, 2], 255, 255, 255), ([0, 2, 3], 255, 0, 0)],
                         dtype=[('vertex_indices', 'i4', (3,)), ('red', 'u1'), ('green', 'u1'), ('blue', 'u1')])
new_vertex = PlyElement.describe(vertex, 'vertex')
with open('colored_points.ply', mode='wb') as f:
    PlyData([plydata, new_vertex], text=True).write(f)
```

This method give me this error:

`AttributeError: 'PlyData' object has no attribute 'name'`

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! We can probably help, but we need more info. Why do you need another method to do it? Is the current method that you're using not satisfying? Please explain why exactly it isn't satisfying. Is there an error message, is the data wrong, etc? Please give details. Also see [What Do You Mean "It Doesn't Work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work) to get inspiration as how to make your question more explicit.

Comment: Also, as a courtesy, could you please edit your question add the relevant `import` lines at the beginning of your code? I could venture a guess that it is `from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement` but that's only a guess. If someone wants to help you, the first thing that they'll do is try to run your code, and it will simply crash without the imports.

Comment: Anyway, if you're really looking for other options, there is this one: https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/blob/master/pyntcloud/io/ply.py

Comment: Ok, i modified it thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Explaining the exception:**

`PlyData` represents the entire ply and is divided into elements, which you can access with: `plydata.elements`.

Example of ply file which has "vertex" element (containing **all** points) and a "face" element (containing **all** faces):

```
plydata.elements
(PlyElement('vertex', (PlyProperty('x', 'float'), PlyProperty('y', 'float'), PlyProperty('z', 'float'), PlyProperty('red', 'uchar'), PlyProperty('green', 'uchar'), PlyProperty('blue', 'uchar')), count=46596, comments=[]),
 PlyElement('face', (PlyListProperty('vertex_indices', 'uchar', 'int'),), count=91800, comments=[]))
```

When you write `PlyData([.., ..], ..)`, it expects a list of `PlyElement` whereas plydata is `PlyData`.

**How to add points to a ply:**

You can access an element with it's name like a dict: `plydata['vertex']`, and the actual data (*numpy*) with `plydata['vertex'].data`

The new points should be added directly to this *data*:

```
new_vertex = numpy.array(
    (1., 2., 3., 10, 20, 30),
    dtype=plydata['vertex'].data.dtype
)
plydata['vertex'].data = np.r_[plydata['vertex'].data, new_vertex]

...

plydata.write(f)
```